# How to capture Telnet traffic in Wireshark?

Tags: wireshark, telnet, traffic

I am new in Wireshark. My question is about Telnet and Eclipse. I have a program who communicate with Telnet. As you see in picture, When I write `"a"` in Telnet, [97] can be seen in Eclipse console as ASCII.

When i check `Wireshark`, I can not see any traffic on Telnet. When I filter as `"ip.dst==10.10.10.12 && tcp.dstport==5000"` or `"tcp.port==23"` or "Telnet", there is no data in wireshark. I guess, there is a problem in wireshark to see Telnet communication. How can i solve this problem?

Please check the screenshot.

Thanks in advance.[Screenshot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwXkm.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I assume your machine's IP address is 10.10.10.12 and that you are telneting from your machine to itself, right?

I don't know Windows, especially how network data are captured by a program like Wireshark, so I may be completely wrong. But I bet Wireshark on Windows can only see packets that actually use your network adapter (WLAN), i.e. which come from or go to an external machine. Traffic that stay inside your machine is probably invisible to it and to any program of that kind (because it's an limitation of the OS).

Instead of telneting to your WLAN IP address, you may try telneting to localhost (127.0.0.x) and make Wireshark spy on the loopback interface.